# Postgresql 9.5 JSON problems

Tags: postgresql-9.5, json

I have to update a complex query that takes JSON fields:

```
SELECT grower, fieldname as "Field/Block/Block Name", downloaddate, area, LandType
from
SELECT context->>'Source' as Product,
       context->>'SourceType' as Producttype ....
```

It uses the Product field at the bottom to search on.

But the original query uses

```
SELECT context::JSON, r.rboundaryid ...
```

and this doesn't work, giving a JSON error:

```
 invalid input syntax for type json
```

The 'context' field in the table is OK JSON as verified by Jsonlint.

I tried changing to

```
 SELECT to_json(context) as jcontext ...
```

changing the top ->> constructs to use the 'jcontext' name ... and this
eliminates the error ... but only because the result is NULL, not a JSON object ...

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the screening part of the query was out of sync with the current database.

The corrected version uses:

```
context::json as contextobj
```

(like my effort)

```
WHERE typecode = 'IMAGERY'
    AND context != '  '
    AND r.createdon > '1/1/2016'
```

I didn't have this part.